# Sonatype OSS 3.28.1-01: Can't Delete specific directory having jar files using cURL

Tags: linux, api, curl, nexus, sonatype

I am using the following cURL command to delete one directory from a repository:

```
curl --request DELETE --user "login:password" http://myNexus/service/local/repositories/myRepository/content/myGroupId/myArtifactId/myVersion/myArtifactId-myVersion.jar
```

But in my Linux CLI, no output is coming, even no error, and also the jar is not deleting.

Also can't delete the maven version build from the repo.
[The component I want to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL4qU.png)

Comment: Try adding "-v" to the curl command so you can see what error is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the same by using the below cURL

```
curl -X DELETE -u <Username>:<Password> http://<Nexus Host IP Address>:8081/repository/<repository>/com/dir1/dir2/<build name>/<build_version>/<Build Name>.jar
```

Moreover we need to remove any other residues like **jar.md5** , **jar.sha1** ,**pom** , **pom.md5** , **pom.sha1**

When all the files under the build directory gets cleared off , the directory also gets deleted from nexus.